# Login - sqlite problems

Tags: android, sqlite

i am trying to use where clause to select memberid and password to verify the user credentials. but it's sayin this column doesnt exists... i tried searching the internet for various ways but no help...please help me .. here is my code

```
public boolean memberlogin(String member_id,String password)throws SQLException{
String[] result=new String[]{member_id,password};
String whereclause="member_id=? AND password=?";
Cursor cur=sdb.query(DB_TABLE, result, whereclause, null, null, null, null);
if(cur!=null)
{
    if(cur.getCount()>0)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;

}
```

Comment: You need to give us the exact error message (and the schema of DB_TABLE..?)

Comment: Btw, unless this is a test application that you are creating to learn something I'd HIGHLY advise you against storing member credentials, i.e username, password in your local database. I guess if you hashed them or hashed+salted them then you could potentially save them safely.

Answer (score 3):

Well you seem to be using the the  arguments in wrong place
  Try This,

```
  String[] columns =new String[]{ COLUMN_ID_NAME ,COLUMN_PASSWORD_NAME};
  String[] result=new String[]{member_id,password};
  String whereclause="member_id=? AND password=?";
  Cursor cur=sdb.query(DB_TABLE, columns , whereclause, result, null, null, null);
```

Comment: hey @darshanz... this worked.. but lols its not verifying da user even tough it is der in da database... hopefully i will correct this issue... thanks buddy